# Conda fails to update Spyder dependencies

Tags: dependencies, updates, spyder, conda

When I called

```
conda update spyder
```

and then opened spyder, I got the following error.

[image]

Is `conda update` supposed to install dependencies for the package being updated?

What is the best way to fix the issue?

Should I just call `conda install jedi`?

Comment: AFAIK, `conda update package` only updates `package`, and does not consider dependencies. Your best course of action is indeed to install `jedi`. I'm not putting this as an answer because I haven't gone through the conda source to verify :-)

Comment: Interesting.  It seems like that would make `conda update` less useful.  Maybe `conda install` with the newest version of the package to install is a better method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the [repodata.json](https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json) of the defaults channel (win-64) of Conda, specifies `jedi>=0.8`:

```
"spyder-3.0.0-py34_0.tar.bz2": {
      "app_entry": "spyder",
      "app_type": "desk",
      "build": "py34_0",
      "build_number": 0,
      "date": "2016-09-26",
      "depends": [
        "jedi >=0.8",
        "nbconvert",
        "pep8",
        "pickleshare",
        "psutil",
        "pyflakes",
        "pygments >=2.0",
        "pylint",
        "pyqt 5.*",
        "python 3.4*",
        "pyzmq",
        "qtawesome",
        "qtconsole >=4.2",
        "qtpy >=1.1",
        "rope",
        "sphinx"
      ],
      "icon": "9779607c273dc0786bd972b4cb308b58.png",
      "license": "MIT",
      "md5": "1e22cec14b87602a6338a3c46b7991ed",
      "name": "spyder",
      "size": 3050583,
      "summary": "Scientific Python Development Environment",
      "type": "app",
      "version": "3.0.0"
    },
```

Now, in the spider repo, at tag [v3.0.0](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/v3.0.0/setup.py#L274), the there is no minimum version of jedi specified at

```
install_requires = [
    'rope_py3k' if PY3 else 'rope>=0.9.4',
    'jedi',
    'pyflakes',
    'pygments>=2.0',
    'qtconsole>=4.2.0',
    'nbconvert',
    'sphinx',
    'pep8',
    'pylint',
    'psutil',
    'qtawesome',
    'qtpy>=1.1.0',
    'pickleshare',
    'pyzmq'
]
```

The [commit](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/commit/43f22281b10a7ad0e89f7dc29327d186818f26ee) to fix this was brought in spyder on Sunday, 5 Feb 2017 and was released in [v3.1.3](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blame/v3.1.3/CHANGELOG.md#L57), which has not been added to the defaults channel of Conda as of Friday, 10 March 2017.

Because of the aforementioned reasons, the upgrade did not update the dependency on jedi.

Since `jedi=0.9.0` is available in the defaults Conda channel, you should be able to get rid of this problem just by doing:

```
conda update jedi
```